# generate a "create table" sql command based on an existing table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql shell but for security reasons I cannot run the mysqldump command.

I have a table that I made a while ago with a lot of columns, and I want to generate a new "create table" command to create that table on a different database.

Is there some command I can run in the mysql shell to generate that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should work:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name
```

You should have SELECT privileges for the table.

Answer (score 15):

FYI, if your user has access to both databases on the same server, you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE db2.tablename LIKE db1.tablename;
```